Issue pyinstaller/tkinter
Running from Windows prompt:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --hidden-import tkinter --icon "C:/Andrea/Script/icon005.ico" "C:/Andrea/Script/script001.py"

I get the following error
file "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon005.ico" not defined

icon file I wanna attach is .ico 16x16
python version is 3.92
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.iconbitmap('icon005.ico')

I also tried to attach the same icon in .gif format but it I get other errors

The exception should not be raised when running pyinstaller.  Most likely it is raised when the script is executed.

The exception should not be raised when executing pyinstaller.  It is raised when running the generated executable.
You need to include the icon file into the executable by using --add-data option of pyinstaller:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --hidden-import tkinter --icon "C:/Andrea/Script/icon005.ico" --add-data "C:/Andrea/Script/icon005.ico":. "C:/Andrea/Script/script001.py"


Now it works (finally) but just in one PC but I also need to run this .exe in another pc.
After creating the .exe, the error that I get is the following:
Unhandled exception in script
Failed to execute script 'script01' due to unhandled exception: bitmap "icon05.ico" not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script01.py", line 387, in <module>
    File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
    _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon05.ico" not defined

I also tried to create the entire directory with this command:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "C:/icon05.ico" --add-data "C:/icon05.ico;." --hidden-import "tkinter"  "C:/script01.py"


Don't ask question in answer section.  It is better to raise another question because it is new issue.

If you are experiencing a different issue, create a different question.  Don't forget to say how you fixed the issue if you fixed it yourself, or upvote + mark as accepted the fix that worked
